# Webpack + Vue Storefront: dist .js file contains multiple "\n//\n"

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-harmony, vue-storefront

I'm working on a Vue Storefront ([link to Github repo](https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront)) project and looking at a filed build by Webpack I see that is full of

```
\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n/* harmony default export */
```

sometimes this string is even longer, like:

> \n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n\n\n\n\n\n/* harmony default export */

this is at the end of a file path and it looks something like this:

> **webpack_require**(123);\n\n// CONCATENATED MODULE: ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./mypath/MyFile.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n//\n\n\n\n\n\n/* harmony default export */

Since the project is quite big and the bundled files are huge, I was wondering what those "\n//\n" stand for and in case if there's a way to get rid of them, or reduce them in order to save some kb on the final generated file.

The webpack files are the default ones: [Github link](https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront/tree/master/core/build)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the webpack config which you use to compile, to the question?

Comment: @ChathurangaK I've added the link to the Github repo i used on my project. Webpack files are linked in the updated question above. Thanks